# passing an array to json.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to pass an array to json.stringify but the returned value is coming  back empty.

```
JSON.stringify({ json: data }) // returns `{"json":[]}`
```

And here would be the contents of data:

```
data[from] = "bfleming@test.com"
data[to] = "test@test.com"
data[message] = "testmessage"
```

jquery:

```
function SubmitUserInformation($group) {
    var data = {};
    data = ArrayPush($group);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.mlaglobal.com/components/handlers/FormRequestHandler.aspx/EmailFormRequestHandler",
        data: JSON.stringify({ json: data }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg) {
                $('emailForm-content').hide();
                $('emailForm-thankyou').show();
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            form.data("validator").invalidate(msg);
        }
    });
}

function ArrayPush($group) {
    var arr = new Array();
    $group.find('input[type=text],textarea').each(function () {
        arr[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
    });
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = ArrayPush($group);
```

Is re-assigning `data` to be an array, so all your expando properties are not being stringified.

Inside your ArrayPush method, change

```
var arr = new Array();
```

to

```
var obj = { };
```

Answer (score 2):

`arr` should be declared as an object inside `ArrayPush` method because you are not using it like an array. Also inside the function you can just use `this.id` and `this.value` you don't have to create the `jQuery` object. Try this

```
function ArrayPush($group) {
    var arr = {};
    $group.find('input[type=text],textarea').each(function () {
        arr[this.id] = this.value;
    });
    return arr;
}
```